# Is <iframe> a good solution for including content from another website?

Tags: html, iframe

Is `<iframe>` a good solution for including some portion of some site into another?

I've heard before that it is a security compromise, ain't it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are security concerns for your users, plus that `<iframe>` can just bust itself and take over the entire page, redirecting from yours.  Any malware they're hosting, XSS attacks, etc. your users would be exposed to, just as if they visited the other site directly.

More than this, unless you *own* the content from the other site, should you really be taking their content in pieces and displaying it in your site to begin with?

Comment: For example, try pointing an `<iframe>` to Stack Overflow; it'll pop up a alert (or a confirmation dialog, I can't quite remember) and then 'bust' out of the `iframe`.

Comment: @David - yup, first line of the `master.js` here: `if(top!=self){top.location.replace(document.location);alert("For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.")}`